# Remove entity: Attaching an entity of type 'X' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-of-work

**I'm trying to implement the design pattern Unit Of Work with Repository/Service.**

I have:

> UnitOfWork
>
> ShoppinglistController
>
> ShoppinglistService
>
> IShoppinglistRepository (which inherits from IRepository)
>
> ShoppinglistRepostiry (which inherits from Repository)

Now I'm trying to remove a list of Products.

**ShoppinglistController:**

```
_service.RemoveRange(products);

_service.Remove(shoppinglistInDb);

_service.Complete();
```

**ShoppinglistService:**

```
public void Remove(Shoppinglist shoppinglist)
{
    _unitOfWork.Shoppinglists.Attach(shoppinglist);
    _unitOfWork.Shoppinglists.Remove(shoppinglist);
}
public void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<Product> products)
{
    _unitOfWork.Products.AttachRange(products);
    _unitOfWork.Products.RemoveRange(products);
}
public void Complete()
{
    _unitOfWork.Complete();
}
```

**Repository:**

```
public void Remove(TEntity entity)
{
    _context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
}
public void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
{
    _context.Set<TEntity>().RemoveRange(entities);
}
public void AttachRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
{
    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        _context.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
    }
}
```

**UnitOfWork**

```
public int Complete()
{
    return _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

When I run this I get the following error message:

> **System.InvalidOperationException:** 'Attaching an entity of type 'MyApp.Models.Product' failed because another entity of the same type
>   already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the
>   'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or
>   'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values.
>   This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received
>   database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or
>   the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of
>   non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.'

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I had to set my product list to null.

```
_service.RemoveRange(products);

shoppinglistInDb.Products = null;

_service.Remove(shoppinglistInDb);

_service.Complete();
```

Now it works.